# How to add custom button to facebook homepage

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am not sure what the correct way to ask this question is.

I will post a screen capture and let that assist me.

Notice the bottom of the screen capture. There is a row of buttons. They are Pictures, Likes, and BookNow buttons. How are buttons added to that location? What is the name of that portion of the screen? How can I add a button like the BookNow button?

[image]

Comment: The only way you can add to this list of buttons is by adding an application to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These buttons are called **Tabs** which are displayed on a Facebook Page. There are few tabs provided by Facebook that a Page Admin can add to his page like *Events Tab*, *Videos Tab*, *Photos Tab* and *Likes Tab*.

Page Admins can additionally install other custom or available **Page Tabs** as per the requirement to increase the User's engagement with the Page. **BookNow! App** in your attached screenshot is a custom Page Tab that the Page has installed to allow other Page Admins to add the same to their Business Pages.

To add a custom Page Tab to your Business page you need to invoke the [Add Page Tab Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/) box and select the Page from the list of Pages that your administer to add the Page Tab.